# ERROR: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2. Advice?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to pull data out of a database that I have created using pgAdmin. I have used the query within pgAdmin and it works fine however when I put this query into my code I get an error.

Here is the SQL for the tracks table:

```
 -- Table: public.tracks

 -- DROP TABLE public.tracks;

 CREATE TABLE public.tracks
 (
trackid integer NOT NULL,
trackname text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
album text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
mainartist text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
feat text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
releasedate text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
filelink text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tracks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (trackid, trackname),
CONSTRAINT track UNIQUE (trackname)
 ,
CONSTRAINT album FOREIGN KEY (album)
    REFERENCES public.albums (albumname) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT artist FOREIGN KEY (mainartist)
    REFERENCES public.artists (stagename) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
 )
 WITH (
OIDS = FALSE
 )
 TABLESPACE pg_default;

 ALTER TABLE public.tracks
OWNER to postgres;
```

Here is the code I am attempting to use, which includes the query:

```
 String SQL = "SELECT trackName, albumName FROM public.tracks, 
 public.albums WHERE tracks.trackname = 'Jungle' AND tracks.mainartist = 
 albums.artist;";
    try
    {
        org.postgresql.Driver.isRegistered();
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password); //creates a new connection

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        if (resultSet.next()) {

            String album = resultSet.getString(3);
            String artist = resultSet.getString(4);
            String trackName = resultSet.getString(2);
            String feat = resultSet.getString(5);
            String date = resultSet.getString(6);

            console.println("");
            console.println("");
            console.println("Track Name: "+trackName);
            console.println("");
            console.println("Track Album: "+album);
            console.println("");
            console.println("Track Artist(s): "+artist);
            console.println("");
            console.println("Featuring: "+feat);
            console.println("");
            console.println("Track Release Date: "+date);
            console.println("");
            console.println("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            console.println("ERROR: There were no matching rows");
        }
```

I am getting the error message of:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
```

And the StackTrace is:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.checkColumnIndex(PgResultSet.java:2755)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.checkResultSet(PgResultSet.java:2775)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getString(PgResultSet.java:1894)
at Info.songInfo(Info.java:48)
at __SHELL10.run(__SHELL10.java:5)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:752)
```

Comment: Your SELECT only returns two columns (index 1 and 2 for `ResultSet.getXX()`) but you are trying to access indexes 2 through 6 - you need to include all columns you want in the `SELECT` list

Comment: Thank you, I have now managed to get this working :)